# C recursive function for product receiving segmentation fault

Tags: c, recursion

I am having difficulty with this problem. The given code is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

//returns the product(5,10) = 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 * 10;

int product(int a, int b) 
{
    int mid;
    if (a == b) 
       return a;
    else {
      mid = (a + b) / 2;
      return product(a, mid) + product(mid,b);
   }   
}

int main() {

    int p;
    p = product(5,10);
    printf("product is %d\n", p);

    return 0;

}
```

The goal of this program is to multiply all the numbers in a given range, for this example, between 5 and 10 (I.E. 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 * 10). The problem uses a recursive function to do this, however in its current state the function calls itself without stopping to the point of overflowing the stack, causing the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". This is an assignment, so I ask that you don't give me solution but rather some tips to point me in the right direction. Thank you very much and please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I think its because this product (5,10) never ends..consider what happens for Product(5,6) and product(6,7) they never end

Comment: Yes, I noticed that when printing the numbers. I think the problem lies in the base case if (a==b).

Comment: Why are you adding in a function that returns a product?

Comment: Expect `product(mid,b)` call to need a value greater than `mid`, not equal.

Comment: I found return product(a, mid) * product(mid+1,b); to work. I believe this is because if the mid was left the same in the second product call, the function would continuously repeat itself, but I'm having difficulty understanding this function. Could someone explain why this change needed to be made?

Comment: because product(5,10) -> product(5,7)+product(8,10) ,its because product(5,7) takes care 5*6*7 and product(8,10) gives you 8*9*10 ...if it was product(7,10) everything would repeat hope u understand..chux pointed an important thing,i dont mind if you unaccept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of taking the mid.You can consider doing like this too
check the following code

```
int product(int a, int b) 
{

    if (a >= b) 
       return a;
    else {

      return a*product(a+1,b);
   }   
}

int main() {

    int p;
    p = product(5,10);
    printf("product is %d\n", p);

    return 0;

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This can create a stack depth of `n` unlike OP's max stack depth of `log2 n`

Comment: @chux..absolutely right , i missed that ..thanks for pointing me to it

Answer (score 2):

I see in the comments to your question that you found that you needed to change your return statement to:

```
return product(a, mid) * product(mid + 1, b);
```

Since you asked for an explanation for why this works, I will provide one. First, it is necessary to obtain the correct calculation. That is:

```
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 --> (1 * 2) * (3 * 4 * 5)
```

But it is not true that this product is equal to (1 * 2) * (2 * 3 * 4 * 5), and certainly 5! is not equal to the sum of these two terms (as you had in your original code).

Second, the reason that the recursion failed to terminate before you made this change is that, as you divide the intervals, you will always end with some intervals of length 1. Your base case requires that all intervals be decomposed into intervals of length 0. As you have defined it, the `mid` of the interval [1, 2] is 1. In fact, the `mid` of the interval [a, a+1] is:

```
mid(a, a+1) = (a + a + 1) / 2 = (2a + 1) / 2 = a + 1/2 = a
```

This means that `product(a, a+1) --> product(a, a) * product(a, a+1)`. In your original scheme, you had, for example:

```
product(1, 2) --> product(1, 1) * product(1, 2)
              --> 1 * product(1, 1) * product(1, 2)
              --> 1 * 1 * product(1, 1) * product(1, 2) ....
```

You kept duplicating intervals that were failing as base cases. With the corrected return statement you have:

```
product(1, 2) --> product(1, 1) * product(2, 2)  
              --> 1 * 2  
              --> 2
```